# Jdbc Acknowledgment (ACK) in Mule

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-el, mule-component, mule-cluster

I like to update my database column deltaprocessstatus as 'I' after fetching the data from database.

Below is my code

```
<spring:beans> 
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:mule-app.properties"/>
    </spring:beans>
    <jdbc-ee:mssql-data-source name="MS_SQL_Data_Source" user="Ssssss" password="ffff" url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost" transactionIsolation="UNSPECIFIED" doc:name="MS SQL Data Source"/>
    <jdbc-ee:connector name="ProSFDB" dataSource-ref="MS_SQL_Data_Source" validateConnections="true" queryTimeout="-1" pollingFrequency="0" doc:name="Database" transactionPerMessage="false">
        <jdbc-ee:query key="SelectAllUser" value="SELECT top 100 * from master_user_Queue"/>
        <jdbc-ee:query key="SelectAllUser.ack" value="update master_user_Queue set DeltaProcessStatus = 'I' where MasterUserID = 1"/>
        <jdbc-ee:query key="SelectbatchWiseInfo" value="Select top 100 * from  master_user_Queue where MasterUserID between #[payload['min']] and #[payload['max']]"/>

    </jdbc-ee:connector>
    <amqp:connector name="AMQP_Connector" validateConnections="true" host="${amqp.host}" port="${amqp.port}" virtualHost="${amqp.virtualhost}" username="${amqp.username}" password="${amqp.password}" doc:name="AMQP Connector"/>

    <spring:beans>
        <spring:bean id="objectStore" name="Bean" class="org.mule.util.store.SimpleMemoryObjectStore"/>       
    </spring:beans>

    <data-mapper:config name="Map_To_Map" transformationGraphPath="map_to_map.grf" doc:name="Map_To_Map"/>

    <flow name="asi_1_user_deactivationFlow1" doc:name="asi_1_user_deactivationFlow1" processingStrategy="synchronous">
        <jdbc-ee:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way"  queryTimeout="-1" pollingFrequency="6000" doc:name="Database" connector-ref="ProSFDB" queryKey="SelectAllUser" tracking:enable-default-events="true">
            <jdbc-ee:transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN"/>
        </jdbc-ee:inbound-endpoint>
</flow>
```

the query key "SelectAllUser" is working fine but the querykey "SelectAllUser.ack" is not working once the "SelectAllUser" is called. I don't know where I am going wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is happening when you run it? Are you just not getting database updates? Anything in the console log indicating failures?

Comment: @SteveS I am not getting the database updates . I didn't get any failure while running the flow.

Comment: So the same rows are getting selected again and again, right?

Comment: Yes David, But my flow is not empty I am using many trasformeer and message processor, I didnt include my full code to avoid the lengthiness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SelectAllUser` is missing a where clause that would make `SelectAllUser.ack` useful.

Indeed, the ack query sets `DeltaProcessStatus = 'I'` but the select query doesn't check that `DeltaProcessStatus != 'I'`. Therefore the same rows will be selected again and again.

Also the fact that the ack query as a where clause with `MasterUserID = 1` but not the select query is highly suspicious. There's a risk the updated rows are not matching the selected ones.

*EDIT*: Another potential issue you are having is that you are starting a transaction in the inbound endpoint but there is nothing that concludes this transaction since the flow is empty. Can you try removing the transaction element? It is useless anyway as long as the flow is empty...

Comment: Thanks for your reply David, I edited my code but still my ack was not yet called automatically.                                        <jdbc-ee:connector name="ProSFDB" dataSource-ref="MS_SQL_Data_Source" validateConnections="true" queryTimeout="-1" pollingFrequency="0" doc:name="Database" transactionPerMessage="false">
        <jdbc-ee:query key="SelectAllUser.ack" value="update master_user_Queue set DeltaProcessStatus = 'I' where MasterUserId between 1 and 100"/>
        <jdbc-ee:query key="SelectAllUser" value="SELECT top 100 * FROM master_user_Queue where DeltaProcessStatus!='I'"/>

Comment: OK, added a note regarding the fact start a transaction but don't end it.